# Unable to resolve module ../../../../src/graphql/error/GraphQLError

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I am creating an app using React Native Expo and AWS Amplify. The project is working previously but a while ago I have encountered this Error.

Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve module ../../../../src/graphql/error/GraphQLError from \node_modules@aws-amplify\api-graphql\lib-esm\GraphQLAPI.js:

None of these files exist:

- src\graphql\error\GraphQLError(.native|.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
- src\graphql\error\GraphQLError\index(.native|.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)

```
> 1 | var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || function () {
  2 |     __assign = Object.assign || function(t) {
  3 |         for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
  4 |             s = arguments[i];
```

Tried deleting Node Modules and reinstall but somehow the error still exist.
Tried to install graphql as dependency and the error still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Install the following `graphql` dependency.

- If you need the GraphQL capability in your app, install as a Prod dependency
  `npm i graphql@15.5.0`
- Otherwise install as a Dev dependency.
  `npm i -D graphql@15.5.0`

Comment: Hi, the error still occurs. I tried both of them using yarn

Comment: Seems something wrong with the setup. Should not look above `\node_modules`. It seems it is looking in the `src` directory for `graphql`. Can you share a bare minimum repo replicating this issue.

Comment: Any updates here? Just ran into this as well.